# How do I make sure the data I am importing is the correct data type?

Tags: postgresql, casting

I have a data_load table with data all in character varying form. I want to take some of that data and convert it into integers and such, and put it in another table. Some of the data is not correct on purpose, so that I can deal with duplicates and values in columns that don't convert to the correct data type. How do I only import data that can be converted to the data type I want?

[image: data_load table]

For example the first row has X as a rep_id, how do I ignore that line from the database

currently what I have is:

```
INSERT INTO rep(rep_id, first_name, last_name, base_salary) 
SELECT DISTINCT rep_id::integer, first_name, last_name, base_salary::integer 
FROM data_load;
```

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find the `try_cast()` function?

Comment: I was just looking up sql tools online, if there is a better way to do this please let me know. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: 1) What  type is `sku` presently? 2) Are the values for `sku` all numeric characters? 3) What if you do ` ... SELECT sku::integer ...` etc? 4) If `product` is already `varchar` going into `varchar` there is no need to do a `CAST`. Add answers to previous as update to your question.

Comment: 1) sku is an integer, 2) there are some instances where the data is not the correct data type, in that case I don't want to include that data, 3) this is what I was looking for thanks, 4) true. thank you, I updated my question. @AdrianKlaver

Comment: The manual of the product you are working with is the first place to start looking. Not some random places in the internet. And if you do search the internet, you should at least verify that the found solutions are for the database you are using.